# Java applet fails to show &rsquo; randomly

Tags: java, applet

My Java applet fails to show HTML-encoded  ’ (`&rsquo;`) on `JTextPanel` panel randomly. Is this a JRE-specific bug? It works OK with my test pc but the customer has a problem that encoding is shown on GUI.

Comment: Does that same thing happen if you use &#8216; ?

Answer (score 0):

This can occur due to the text encoding of your Java source file. The best solution is to ensure you use UTF-8 in the source files. A similar problem recently occurred to me with the pound symbol, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006688/how-do-i-show-the-pound-sterling-sign-in-java-swing).